# MIT 6.0001 Pset 1c Bisectional Search question

Tags: python

Link to pset 1(https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf)

Hello,

I've been working through the bisectional search problem for the MIT 6.0001 course's pset1. I feel like I have all components down, but it keeps giving me the same answer for savings rate and steps in bisectional search no matter what input I give. Could anyone tell me what I have done wrong here?

```
# User input
annual_salary = float(input('Enter the starting salary: ' ))

# Given sets of assumption
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
portion_down_payment = 0.25
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04   # Annual investment interest rate of current savings 
down_payment = portion_down_payment * total_cost

num_guess = 0  # Bisectional search guess count starts at 0

# Lowest and highest integer savings rate in intial bisection search 
low = 0
high = 10000
guess = (high + low)//2.0

while abs(down_payment - current_savings) >= 100:
    current_savings = 0
    rate = guess/10000
    for month in range(36):
        if month%6 == 0 and month > 0:
            annual_salary += annual_salary * semi_annual_raise  
        monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
        current_savings += (rate * monthly_salary) + current_savings*(r/12)
# Bisectional search introduced
    if current_savings < down_payment:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (high + low)//2.0
    num_guess += 1 
    if num_guess > 13:
        break
print('Best savings rate:', rate)
print('Steps in bisection search:', num_guess)
```

Comment: Can't you just do intermediate prints to find out where logic goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the `annual_salary` variable to its original value (value from the input) each time before going through the [for loop] because each iteration tries a different saving rate guessing with the same starting salary.

I suggest you use a different variable (e.g. updated_annual_salary) and assign the starting salary to it to be able to reset it over and over.

Another thing is that when the annual salary gets updated, the monthly salary gets updated too and so does the saved portion. So, your [while loop] should start like this:

```
while abs(down_payment - current_savings) >= 100:
    updated_annual_salary = annual_salary
    current_savings = 0
    rate = guess / 10000
    for month in range(36):
        if month % 6 == 0 and month > 0:
            updated_annual_salary += updated_annual_salary * semi_annual_raise
        monthly_salary = updated_annual_salary / 12
        current_savings += (rate * monthly_salary) + current_savings * (r / 12)
```